# Style a custom property of a custom control

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

In an application that I am working I need to have all of my next buttons look the same.  So my plan was to make a style called next button style and apply as needed.  However I need to set some dependency properties on the button to be the same.

Here is the xmal for the style

```
<Style x:Key="NextButtonStyle" TargetType="diControls:DIButton">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="DIButtonStyle" Value="DIGreenImageButtonWithText_Medium"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Image" Value="RightArrowIcon_Gray"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HoverImage" Value="RightArrowIcon_White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=NextPressedCommand}"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

The custom properties DIButtonStyle,Image and HoverImage all say an exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Is there any way around this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you meant those values to be static resources?

Comment: joshwl2003 - Can you tell us what type of your dependency properties? If you use images, you can set like Uri or BitmapImage?

Comment: The Images are enums that then have a converter applied to them to get the actual image. We did this so we could leverage the use of intellisense inside of xmal.  The DiButtonStyle is also an enum but it is not a dependency property.